# input ocupe alto y ancho de td table (CSS HTML)

Tags: css

Tengo una tabla HTML:

```html
<style>
  td {
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Campo</th>
      <th>Campo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Quiero hacer algo parecido a **Excel**, es decir que mi `input` ocupe todo el `100%` de mi celda, pero solo logro ocupar el `width` pero no el `height`

Comment: El código que expones parece funcionar, ¿podrías explicar mejor por favor?

Comment: El código parece funcionar, pero realmente lo hace hasta cierto punto. Lo que debes es establecerle unas dimensiones a la celda (`td`) para que adopte la altura que se pretende. Sin embargo, si lo quiere hacer sin darle dimensiones a la celda, entonces, debería prescindir de `%` en el `input`, ya que su contenedor no tiene dimensiones. Me refiero, específicamente al valor `100%` de la propiedad `height`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo faltan algunos detalles para que funcione:

1. Al elemento `input` debes establecerle la propiedad [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) (`box-sizing: border-box`) para que su tamaño total no sea mayor al que se pretende en caso de existir *bordes* y/o rellenos.
2. Colocarle a la celda (`td`) una dimensión (por ejemplo, `height: 30px`):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
  
  /* Por ejemplo, agregar una altura
     en la celda */
  height: 30px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  
  /* El detalle que faltaba que funcione */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Campo</th>
      <th>Campo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Para que cualquier elemento pueda tomar dimensiones definidas en una regla CSS debe ser de bloque, independientemente del tipo de bloque que sea.
>
> También tome en cuenta que si no quiere establecerle una altura a la celda (`td`), sino, directamente a `input`, entonces, debería prescindir de `%`, a menos, que su contenedor padre tenga unas dimensiones establecidas.

Si quiere saber más, puede consultar [**Modelo de caja**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model) en el sitio Web oficial de Mozilla.

Comment: gracias amigo el codigo funciono